# Get the currently used url when an on the template in django for us in a breadcrumb?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, urlconf

I have an app which serves two purposes - displays members and centres of my company. They both work exactly the same, save a different variable when filtering my model. Problem is I can't get the current url onto the template to use in my custom breadcrumbs.

---

I have this urlpattern in my main urls.py:

```
# --- urls.py ---- 
url(r'^find-member/', include('company.directory.urls'), \
        {'which_app': 'members'}, name='find_member'),
url(r'^find-centre/', include('company.directory.urls'), \
        {'which_app': 'training'}, name='find_centre'),
```

of which links to my app urls.py:

```
# ---- company/urls.py ----
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('company.directory.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', 'index'),
)
```

on my template I wish to create a link to the first urlpatten for use with my custom breadcrumbs

```
<a href='/find-member/'>members</a>
```

or

```
<a href='/find-centre/'>Centre</a>
```

based upon which url I'm using the app with.

my view looks like this:

```
# ---- company/view.py ----
def index(request, which_app=None, slug=None):
    #r = reverse('' ,kwargs={'which_app'=training )
    s = "%s %s" % (which_app, slug)

    return render_to_response('directory/index.html', locals())
```

I would like to find the url based upon the `which_app` variable passed into the def. 
I can't seem to use `resolve()` or `reverse()`. I'm probably doing it wrong. I haven't really got a template to show right now.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I'd love some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a function. Your view is passed the `request` object, which has an attribute `path` which is the path that was called. See [the request docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#attributes).